# How to declare static variables as possible return types in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, static, return-type

I'm trying to declare a return type from a simple getter in TypeScript. That return type should conform to one of two static variables, associated with the class that implements them.

Take this code:

```js
class Hairdryer {

  public static ON = 'ON'
  public static OFF = 'OFF'

  private _state: Hairdryer.ON|Hairdryer.OFF = Hairdryer.OFF

  get state (): Hairdryer.ON|Hairdryer.OFF {
    return this._state
  }
}
```

The TypeScript compiler doesn't like this, and throws errors:

> 'Hairdryer' only refers to a type, but is being used as a namespace here.(2702)

> Return type of public getter 'state' from exported class has or is using private name 'Hairdryer'.(4043)

[image]

I know I could just have `'ON'|'OFF'` as my return type, but I wanted to be able to reference the possible types from outside the class, without instantiating it, hence the use of static properties.

Here's a [playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEASYEsBOATJBPApk6BvAUPtNAA4CuARiAsNBAC5j03QDyActALzQDkHvIqUrVaDJi1YAxKdz7SpgoSSQIAbk0zQA+uPqYAXHESoM2AHQcAPvGRosSSzLm3TDp1MLEA5pnp1GfWgACgBKI1d7C2tIs0cFPCFiJD8yJAA7aHoACwQIc11AzCEAX3wSoA).

Answer (score 2):

Ill suggest you to use Enum instead of static values inside the class this is more TS friendly.

```
enum State {
  ON = 'ON',
  OFF = 'OFF'
}

class Hairdryer {

  public static state = State;

  private _state: State= State.OFF

  get state (): State {
    return this._state
  }
}
```

Comment: I do like enums, but I decided against it because I wanted the values to be easily accessed from outside the class. With the above, you would have to import the enum before you were able to use it elsewhere. That's an extra step that I don't want my users/maintainers to have to think about.

Comment: You can also add that as part of the class itself, let me modify the solution that way.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use an index access type on the static part of the class (`typeof Hairdryer` not `Hairdryer`)

```
type State = typeof Hairdryer['ON']| typeof Hairdryer['OFF'];
class Hairdryer {

  public static ON = 'ON' as const
  public static OFF = 'OFF' as const

  private _state: State= Hairdryer.OFF

  get state (): State {
    return this._state
  }
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=12&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAysCGxoF4qkgewGZQBLwEsAnAEyJAiIG0ByAeQDkaBdAHzXAmz0NPMtp0AYkJYBuAFABjADbwAzvJ7EyFIlADeEiVChgArgCMZBKVHkJgpqIyip6TKAqhSMAOws69Rk2YuJrYSE7KHoRGiclVw9gbV0wIgIAN0RoAH1-JAAuWEsIVHwVfiIAOiC4qABzCGBzPKgACgBKHLhUzS9dIhr9Ijc0AAsCeRKMvK8AXwkJoA)